# Trying to resolve a syntax error for MYSQL update trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I am trying to create a trigger to update the `Project` table whenever the `Assign` table is updated, yet I keep receiving this error:  `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF`

Does anyone have any idea of why I am getting this syntax error?  Please note that I am a beginner at this so my SQL statements may be entirely wrong. Also, I know for sure that my query being ran in my IF statement works because I've ran it on its own without being inside a trigger.

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON Assign
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF OLD.projNo <> new.projNo THEN
    
    #RUN THIS QUERY TO UPDATE MY TABLE

    
        UPDATE Project p JOIN 
          (SELECT Project.projNo, COUNT(DISTINCT empid) as numEmployeeAssigned
            FROM (Project LEFT JOIN Assign ON Project.projNo=Assign.projNo) 
            GROUP BY projNo
            ) as tb 
            ON p.projNo = tb.projNo
            SET p.numEmployeeAssigned = tb.numEmployeeAssigned
            
     #END QUERY
     
    END IF
  END$$
delimiter;
```

Comment: You need a semicolon at the end of the UPDATE statement.

Comment: @BillKarwin whenever I add a semicolon to the end of the UPDATE the syntax error is not resolved -- thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You can just increment or decrement the count:

```
   UPDATE Project p
        SET p.numEmployeeAssigned = p.numEmployeeAssigned +
                                    (case when p.projNo = new.ProjNo then 1 else -1 end)
        WHERE p.projNo IN (old.ProjNo, new.ProjNo) AND
              old.ProjNo <> new.ProjNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, your code is missing semi-colons after the `UPDATE` statement and after the `END IF`.

However, let me suggest that the `UPDATE` statement could most likely be simplified. As I understand your code, you want to update the count of employees in `Project` whenever an employee changes its assignment. If so, there is no need to actually query `assign`. You can just use conditional logic like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON Assign
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.projNo <> new.projNo THEN
        UPDATE Project p
        SET numEmployeeAssigned = CASE 
            WHEN projNo =  new.projNo THEN numEmployeeAssigned + 1
            ELSE numEmployeeAssigned - 1
        END
        WHERE projNo IN (OLD.projNo, NEW.projNo);
    END IF;
END$$
```

You could even remove the `IF` statement and put that condition in the query directly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON Assign
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Project p
    SET numEmployeeAssigned = CASE 
        WHEN projNo =  new.projNo THEN numEmployeeAssigned + 1
        ELSE numEmployeeAssigned - 1
    END
    WHERE projNo IN (OLD.projNo, NEW.projNo) AND OLD.projNo <> NEW.projNo
END$$
```

Comment: thanks for this, this worked perfectly!  Can you explain the logic on line 10 of your first code-snippet:     "...WHERE projNo IN (OLD.projNo, NEW.projNo);"

Comment: @emonz: the idea is to select projects that are related to the triggering update statement. Withdraw 1 from the old project, add 1 to the new one. ` projNo IN (OLD.projNo, NEW.projNo)` is equivalent to `projNo = OLD.projNo OR projNo = NEW.projNo`.